# How to check/uncheck a Checkbox inside a stateful child WIdget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, checkbox, children, stateful

I ahve a parent Widget called `LockTimelogsList`, which contains a `ListView` of `LockTimelogBox`. Each child widget/`LockTimelogBox` contains a `Checkbox` I need to update from the parent `LockTimelogsList`. When the user presses "Select all" or "Deselect all", `LockTimelogsList` needs to iterate though the `LockTimelogBoxes` and set the checkbox inside each to true/false.

The trouble I'm having is that iterating the listed child widgets and changing the and updating their checkbox bool value, the checkbox does not update it's view, even after calling `setState`.

I've tried two approaches:

- Changing the checkbox bool value directly from the parent within a setState call.
- Calling a function inside each child widget to change the checkbox value from within the child itself.

[image]

## Update

Now the code works. It updates all the checkboxes correctly. Take a look at the accepted answer in case anyone reading this does the same mistakes I did. I updated the code to the working now. You can see the working code below.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Current parent (list) code:

```
class LockTimelogsList extends StatefulWidget {
  LockTimelogsList({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LockTimelogsListState createState() => _LockTimelogsListState();
}

class _LockTimelogsListState extends State<LockTimelogsList> {
  List<TimeLogModel> unlockedLogs;
  List<ProjectModel> projects;
  List<WorkOrderModel> workOrders;
  List<TaskModel> tasks;
  ProjectHttpService projectHttpService;
  WorkOrderHttpService workOrderHttpService;
  TaskHttpService taskHttpService;
  TimeLogHttpService timeLogHttpService;
  double displayHeight;
  double displayWidth;
  bool selectAllOptionActive;
  List<LockTimelogBox> timelogBoxes;
  List<Function> selectFunctions;
  List<Function> deselectFunctions;
  List<TimelogBoxData> boxDatas;
  List<bool> checkboxes;

  @override
  void initState() {
    initServices();
    initValues();
    loadInitData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setDisplayDimensions();
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: buildAppBar(),
      body: buildBody(),
    ));
  }

  buildAppBar() {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: themeConfig.appBarBg,
      title: Row(
        children: [Icon(Icons.lock), Text(" Lås timmar")],
      ),
    );
  }

  buildBody() {
    return Stack(
      children: [buildControlsLayer(), buildLoadDialogLayer()],
    );
  }

  buildControlsLayer() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [buildTopSelectBar(), buildTimelogList()],
    );
  }

  buildLoadDialogLayer() {
    return Container();
  }

  buildTimelogList() {
    return Expanded(
        flex: 100,
        child: Scrollbar(
            child: ListView(
          children: buildTimelogBoxes(),
        )));
  }

  buildTimelogBoxes() {
    var boxDatas = TimelogBoxDataHelper.createList(unlockedLogs, workOrders, tasks, projects);

    var widgets = new List<Widget>();
    timelogBoxes.clear();
    for (var i = 0; i < boxDatas.length; i++) {
      var box = buildTimelogBox(boxDatas[i], checkboxes[i], i);
      widgets.add(box);
      timelogBoxes.add(box);
    }
    this.boxDatas = boxDatas;
    return widgets;
  }

  LockTimelogBox buildTimelogBox(TimelogBoxData boxData, bool isChecked, int listIndex) {
    var box = new LockTimelogBox(
      data: boxData,
      giveSelectFunction: addSelectFunction,
      giveDeselectFunction: addDeselectFunction,
      isChecked: isChecked,
      checkChangeCallback: checkChangeCallback,
      listIndex: listIndex,
    );
    return box;
  }

  void initValues() {
    checkboxes = [];
    boxDatas = [];
    displayHeight = 1;
    displayWidth = 1;
    unlockedLogs = [];
    projects = [];
    workOrders = [];
    tasks = [];
    selectAllOptionActive = true;
    timelogBoxes = [];
    selectFunctions = [];
    deselectFunctions = [];
  }

  Future loadInitData() async {
    await loadTimelogs();
    if (unlockedLogs.length > 0) await loadProjectData();
  }

  void initServices() {
    projectHttpService = new ProjectHttpService();
    workOrderHttpService = new WorkOrderHttpService();
    taskHttpService = new TaskHttpService();
    timeLogHttpService = new TimeLogHttpService();
  }

  void onLoadTimelogsError() {
    MessageDialogHelper.show("Fel vid laddning av tidsloggar", "Fel uppstod vid laddning av tidsloggar.", context);
  }

  void onLoadTimelogsSuccess(Response response) {
    var timelogs = TimelogHelper.getFromJson(response.body);
    setTimelogs(timelogs);
  }

  setTimelogs(List<TimeLogModel> timelogs) {
    setState(() {
      // temp
      timelogs.forEach((log) {
        checkboxes.add(false);
      });
      // -

      unlockedLogs = timelogs;
    });
  }

  Future loadTimelogs() async {
    try {
      var response = await timeLogHttpService.getUnlockedLogs(globals.userId);
      if (HttpHelper.isSuccess(response))
        onLoadTimelogsSuccess(response);
      else
        onLoadTimelogsError();
    } catch (e) {
      onLoadTimelogsError();
    }
  }

  Future loadProjectData() async {
    var futures = new List<Future>();
    futures.add(loadProjects(unlockedLogs));
    futures.add(loadWorkOrders(unlockedLogs));
    futures.add(loadTasks(unlockedLogs));
    var results = await Future.wait(futures);
    var projects = getFromResults<ProjectModel>(results);
    var workOrders = getFromResults<WorkOrderModel>(results);
    var tasks = getFromResults<TaskModel>(results);
    setProjects(projects);
    setWorkOrders(workOrders);
    setTasks(tasks);
  }

  Future<List<ProjectModel>> loadProjects(List<TimeLogModel> timelogs) async {
    var futures = new List<Future<ProjectModel>>();
    var projectIds = TimelogHelper.getProjectIds(timelogs);
    projectIds.forEach((id) {
      futures.add(loadProject(id));
    });
    var projects = await Future.wait(futures);
    return projects;
  }

  Future<ProjectModel> loadProject(String id) async {
    try {
      var response = projectHttpService.getProject(id);
      return response.then<ProjectModel>((resp) {
        if (HttpHelper.isSuccess(resp))
          return ProjectHelper.getSingleFromJson(resp.body, true);
        else
          return null;
      }).catchError((err) {
        return null;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<List<WorkOrderModel>> loadWorkOrders(List<TimeLogModel> timelogs) async {
    var futures = new List<Future<WorkOrderModel>>();
    var workOrderIds = WorkOrderHelper.getWorkOrderIds(timelogs);
    workOrderIds.forEach((id) {
      futures.add(loadWorkOrder(id));
    });
    var workOrders = await Future.wait(futures);
    return workOrders;
  }

  Future<WorkOrderModel> loadWorkOrder(String id) async {
    try {
      var response = workOrderHttpService.get(id);
      return response.then<WorkOrderModel>((resp) {
        if (HttpHelper.isSuccess(resp)) {
          var list = WorkOrderHelper.getSingleFromJson(resp.body, true);
          return list;
        } else
          return null;
      }).catchError((err) {
        return null;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<List<TaskModel>> loadTasks(List<TimeLogModel> timelogs) async {
    var futures = new List<Future<TaskModel>>();
    var taskIds = TaskHelper.getTaskIds(timelogs);
    taskIds.forEach((id) {
      futures.add(loadTask(id));
    });
    var tasks = await Future.wait(futures);
    return tasks;
  }

  Future<TaskModel> loadTask(String id) async {
    try {
      var response = taskHttpService.getById(id);
      return response.then<TaskModel>((resp) {
        if (HttpHelper.isSuccess(resp)) {
          var list = TaskHelper.getSingleFromJson(resp.body, true);
          return list;
        } else
          return null;
      }).catchError((err) {
        return null;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  List<T> getFromResults<T>(List<dynamic> results) {
    List<T> result;
    results.forEach((res) {
      if (res is List<T>) result = res;
    });
    return result;
  }

  setProjects(List<ProjectModel> projects) {
    setState(() {
      this.projects = projects;
    });
  }

  setWorkOrders(List<WorkOrderModel> workOrders) {
    setState(() {
      this.workOrders = workOrders;
    });
  }

  setTasks(List<TaskModel> tasks) {
    setState(() {
      this.tasks = tasks;
    });
  }

  buildTopSelectBar() {
    return Expanded(
        flex: 8,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(width: displayHeight * 0.0005, color: Color(0x77FFFFFF))),
            gradient: LinearGradient(begin: Alignment.topLeft, end: Alignment.bottomRight, colors: [Color(0xFF13313b), Color(0xFF11131a)]),
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: [buildSelectAllButton(), buildSelectCount()],
          ),
        ));
  }

  setDisplayDimensions() {
    if (displayWidth == 1 || displayWidth == null) displayWidth = DisplayHelper.getDisplayWidth(context);
    if (displayHeight == 1 || displayHeight == null) displayHeight = DisplayHelper.getDisplayHeight(context);
  }

  buildSelectAllButton() {
    return Expanded(
        flex: 100,
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: onSelectAllTap,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: displayWidth * 0.03),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: Icon(
                      selectAllOptionActive ? Icons.check_box : Icons.cancel,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: displayWidth * 0.05,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: displayWidth * 0.015),
                    child: Text(
                      selectAllOptionActive ? "Markera alla" : "Avmarkera alla",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: displayWidth * 0.05, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  buildSelectCount() {
    return Expanded(
        flex: 100,
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: InkWell(
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                "",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: displayWidth * 0.05, color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  void onSelectAllTap() {
    setState(() {
      if (selectAllOptionActive)
        selectAll();
      else
        deselectAll();
      setSelectAllOption(!selectAllOptionActive);
    });
  }

  setSelectAllOption(bool selectAllActive) {
    setState(() {
      selectAllOptionActive = selectAllActive;
    });
  }

  void selectAll() {
    print(selectFunctions);
    print(timelogBoxes);
    print(unlockedLogs);
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) checkboxes[i] = true;
    selectFunctions.forEach((func) {
      func();
    });
  }

  void deselectAll() {
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) checkboxes[i] = false;
    deselectFunctions.forEach((func) {
      func();
    });
  }

  addSelectFunction(Function f) {
    selectFunctions.add(f);
  }

  addDeselectFunction(Function f) {
    deselectFunctions.add(f);
  }

  checkChangeCallback(int listIndex, bool isChecked) {
    setState(() {
      checkboxes[listIndex] = isChecked;
      selectAllOptionActive = !checkboxes.any((b) => b);
    });
  }
}
```

Current child (box) code:

```
class LockTimelogBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final TimelogBoxData data;
  final Function giveSelectFunction;
  final Function giveDeselectFunction;
  final bool isChecked;
  final Function checkChangeCallback;
  final int listIndex;

  LockTimelogBox({this.data, this.giveSelectFunction, this.giveDeselectFunction, this.isChecked, this.checkChangeCallback, this.listIndex});

  @override
  TimeLogBoxState createState() => TimeLogBoxState();
}

class TimeLogBoxState extends State<LockTimelogBox> {
  double displayWidth = 1;
  double displayHeight = 1;
  double boxRowFontsizeFactor;
  bool isChecked;

  @override
  void initState() {
    initValues();
    widget.giveSelectFunction(select);
    widget.giveDeselectFunction(deselect);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setDisplayDimensions();
    return Container(
      height: displayHeight * 0.2,
      width: displayWidth,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(begin: Alignment.topLeft, end: Alignment.bottomRight, colors: [Color(0xFF13313b), Color(0xFF11131a)]),
          border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(width: displayHeight * 0.0005, color: Color(0x77FFFFFF)))),
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: onBoxTap,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: [buildCheckBoxContainer(), buildInfoContainer()],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  buildCheckBoxContainer() {
    return Expanded(
        flex: 10,
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: buildCheckbox(),
        ));
  }

  buildInfoContainer() {
    return Expanded(
        flex: 70,
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: displayHeight * 0.005, bottom: displayHeight * 0.005, left: displayWidth * 0.01, right: displayWidth * 0.01),
          child: Column(
            children: [buildDateRow(), buildProjectRow(), buildWorkOrderRow(), buildTaskRow()],
          ),
        ));
  }

  buildCheckbox() {
    return Container(
      child: Theme(
        data: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.green, unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.grey),
        child: Transform.scale(
          scale: 1.5,
          child: Checkbox(
            value: isChecked,
            onChanged: onCheckChange,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onCheckChange(bool isChecked) {
    widget.checkChangeCallback(widget.listIndex, isChecked);
    setIsChecked(isChecked);
  }

  setIsChecked(bool isChecked) {
    if (this.mounted) {
      setState(() {
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
      });
    } else
      this.isChecked = isChecked;
  }

  void onBoxTap() {
    onCheckChange(!isChecked);
  }

  buildDateRow() {
    return Expanded(
        child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.access_time,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: displayWidth * 0.01),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Text(
            DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").format(widget.data.timeLog.start),
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: displayWidth * boxRowFontsizeFactor, color: Colors.white),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ));
  }

  buildProjectRow() {
    return Expanded(
        child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.work,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: displayWidth * 0.01),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Text(
            widget.data.timeLog.projectName,
            maxLines: 1,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: displayWidth * boxRowFontsizeFactor, color: Colors.white),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ));
  }

  buildWorkOrderRow() {
    return Expanded(
        child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.work,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: displayWidth * 0.01),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Text(
            widget.data.workOrder.name,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            maxLines: 1,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: displayWidth * boxRowFontsizeFactor, color: Colors.white),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ));
  }

  buildTaskRow() {
    return Expanded(
        child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.playlist_add_check,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: displayWidth * 0.01),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Text(
            widget.data.timeLog.projectName,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            maxLines: 1,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: displayWidth * boxRowFontsizeFactor, color: Colors.white),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ));
  }

  void initValues() {
    displayWidth = 1;
    displayHeight = 1;
    boxRowFontsizeFactor = 0.05;
    isChecked = widget.isChecked;
  }

  setDisplayDimensions() {
    if (displayWidth == 1 || displayWidth == null) displayWidth = DisplayHelper.getDisplayWidth(context);
    if (displayHeight == 1 || displayHeight == null) displayHeight = DisplayHelper.getDisplayHeight(context);
  }

  select() {
    setIsChecked(true);
  }

  deselect() {
    setIsChecked(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can accomplish this with `Stateless` list-items. If you can use `StatelessWidget`, you should. One way to accomplish this is to store a `List<bool>` and give each child a way to set the `bool` at it's index in the `List`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is mutating something that should be immutable, which is a very bad idea and practice.

The state class is specifically to handle your state change, so what you should instead do is declare a state variable inside the class and since there are multiple checkboxes, initialize a `List<bool> checkBoxes` and map them to using the incoming data from the  `widget.data`  or have separate variables for each if they're not much, and then use them in your `CheckBox()`

```dart
class TimeLogBoxState extends State<LockTimelogBox> {
...

bool isChecked = widget.data.isChecked;


buildCheckbox() {
    return Container(
      child: Theme(
        data: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.green, unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.grey),
        child: Transform.scale(
          scale: 1.5,
          child: Checkbox(
            value: isChecked,
            onChanged:(val){
              setState((){ isChecked = val});
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Something like that.

Comment: I made an update to the post. It almost works now but not entirely. Can you take a look again? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, now I did as you said regarding creating a separate List<bool> to store the Checkbox states whether they are checked or not. Now it works. I will accept your answer and update my code in my question so it can help others. Thanks!